# Maven clean install is equal mvn clean and after mvn install?

Tags: java, performance, maven, installation

I have multimodule maven project. Found that:

mvn clean - takes 3 minutes
after

mvn install - takes 18 minutes.

So I suppose that mvn clean install should take 21 minutes, but it takes near 30 minutes!
So does it the same:

```
mvn clean install
```

and

```
mvn clean
mvn install
```

?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, yes, although I'm a little surprised startup/resolution/etc. takes *that* much time.

Things like OS-caching, JVM startup/optimization/etc., and so on would all play a role in the differences.

Answer (score 2):

let take this example

```
framework
    framework-utils
 foundation
    foundation-model
    foundation-api
    foundation-core

 The call order of my modules:
 1. mvn clean / mvn install:   [clean] framework-utils [clean] 
 foundation-model [clean] foundation-api [clean] foundation-core 
 [install] framework-utils [install] foundation-model [install] 
 foundation-api [install] foundation-core
 2. mvn clean install: [clean] framework-utils [install] 
 framework-utils [clean] foundation-model [install] foundation-model 
 [clean] foundation-api [install] foundation-api [clean] 
 foundation-core [install] foundation-core
```

Comment: So basically: Does it call the same modules? Yes. Does it do them in the same order? No. ...so if you have a long [install] it's better to install multiple modules in one go, rather than intersperse it with [clean]s.